# Como llenar un arrayList de objetos

Tags: java

Hola estoy creando un proyeto para una clase de DPOO y cuando lleno mi arrayList de tipo bebida con objetos de vino y ron(que conste que vino y ron asi como bebida son clase cada una y bebida es la clase padre de vino y ron). Mi arrayList me queda asi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] a la hora de correr el codigo me da un error en la linea 15 o sea cuando estoy añadiendo objetos al arrayList. Que puedo hacer.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: NullPointerException significa que estás intentando acceder/añadir datos a un objeto u array y que la cantidad de parámetros (o el tipo) no coinciden con el constructor de tu objeto, estaría genial que edites tu pregunta y añadas además el constructor de tu objeto Vino y de Fecha

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes definidas las clases `Vino` y `Ron`? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta y pone el código como texto.

Comment: puede que sea por que no as inicializado el ArrayList, lo que compartes da poco información acerca del problema mas aun, aplica las recomendaciones de gbianchi